# RestTemplate OAuth2 request access token via GET request instead of POST

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2, resttemplate

I am using Spring RestTemplate to make requests against an OAuth2 protected resource server. Below is the code that initialises RESTTemplate.

```
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
resourceDetails.setUsername(userName);
resourceDetails.setPassword(password);
resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(root + accessTokenURI);
resourceDetails.setClientId(clientId);
resourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
resourceDetails.setGrantType(grantType);
resourceDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList(scope));

DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();

RestTemplate rest = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);
```

Spring `RestTemplate` by default uses `POST` request to obtain `access_token` from Authorisation Server. I have a unique requirement. I want the `RestTemplate` to use `GET` in order to obtain the `access_token` instead of `POST`. Is there any configuration through which this behaviour can be modified?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution after looking at internals of the [spring-security-oauth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) project. It requires overriding `ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider` class and set it as `AccessTokenProvider` within `OAuth2RestTemplate` class. Here is how it goes.

```
package com.acme;

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;

public class ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider extends org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider {

  @Override
  protected HttpMethod getHttpMethod() {
    return HttpMethod.GET;
  }
}
```

and when you initialise the `OAuth2RestTemplate`

```
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
resourceDetails.setUsername(userName);
resourceDetails.setPassword(password);
resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(root + accessTokenURI);
resourceDetails.setClientId(clientId);
resourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
resourceDetails.setGrantType(grantType);
resourceDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList(scope));

DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();

OAuth2RestTemplate rest = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);

// Set the overridden ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider class instance to OAuth2RestTemplate
AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new com.acme.ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider();
rest.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider);
```